# Error in onActivityResult following migration of StartActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, startactivityforresult

I modified my code so that it works with On activity result however I have an error which I cannot correct on the line profileImageView.setImageURI (ImageUri);

he tells me that he requires Uri and that it comes from Intent

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mGetContent=registerForActivityResult(new 
ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() 
{
@Override
public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
   if (result.getResultCode()==RESULT_OK && result.getData()!=null){
   Intent ImageUri=result.getData();
       profileImageView.setImageURI(ImageUri);
   }
  }
 });


       public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
       galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
   //    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GalleryPick);

       mGetContent.launch(galleryIntent);
   }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the prebuilt [`GetContent` contract](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.GetContent)? That handles all of the parsing for you and gives you a `Uri` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code as follows inside the onActivityResult() method.

```
if(result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){
  Intent data = result.getData();
  if(data != null){
    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
     if(imageUri != null){
       try{
         InputStream inputStream = YourActivityName.this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
         BitMap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
         profileImageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
      }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

And, Your OnClick() method should be something like below:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    mGetContent.launch(intent);
  }
```